# Writing to mysql database PHP. How to update value in field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my mysql table that I want to update.

Example: In my database the field amount has a value of 4 and I want to add 6 to the value.

How would I add 6 to the existing value???

This is what I have so far but this just deletes the existing value and adds a new one:

```
mysql_send("UPDATE peopletable SET amount='$amount' WHERE id='100' ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE peopletable SET amount=amount+6 WHERE id='100'
```

or if $amount is the value that you're adding (6 isn't static)

```
   " UPDATE peopletable SET amount=amount+$amount WHERE id='100'"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to add something to a supplied value:

```
UPDATE peopletable SET amount='$amount' + 6 WHERE id='100'
```

To update the existing value, do:

```
UPDATE peopletable SET amount = ammoutn  + 6 WHERE id='100'
```

Comment: his answer should work! You can also SELECT the value, make your operation in php and then update the db with the new calculated value...

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants. He wants to add 6 to the amount currently stored in the column, not change it to be 6 greater than an arbitrary quantity.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear to me from his example code. I supplied an answer for both options.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE peopletable SET amount=amount + 6 WHERE id='100'
```

or

```
UPDATE peopletable SET amount+= 6 WHERE id='100'
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE peopletable SET amount = amount + 6 WHERE id = 100`

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_send("UPDATE peopletable SET amount=`amount`+6 WHERE id='100' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are sanitising your input and `$amount` is numeric.

Here's what your query should look like:

`mysql_send("UPDATE peopletable SET amount+=$amount WHERE id='100' ");`

This will take the original value and add `$amount` to it.